# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' on line 36

Tags: php, parse-error

This is the complete code:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="pass07"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test_db"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="test_tbl"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">

<?php
// Start looping rows in mysql database.
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td width="10%"><? echo $rows['one']; ?></td>
<td width="30%"><? echo $rows['two']; ?></td>
<td width="30%"><? echo $rows['three']; ?></td>
<td width="30%"><? echo $rows['four']; ?></td>
</tr>


<?php
// close while loop 
}
?>

</table>

<?php
// close MySQL connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

I'm trying to display the information from my DB. When I run the code, it says:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' on line 36
What am I missing? Where am I going wrong?
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
</table>
```

inside your PHP tags.

Change:

```
<?php
// close while loop 
}
</table>
?>
```

To:

```
<?php
// close while loop 
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: @ Wayne Whitty. Thank you kindly. That was very helpful. I get not empty table!

Comment: Thanks to Wayne. The code is updated. But now displaying an empty table. Please help if you can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have `short_open_tag` set to `on` in your `php.ini`, you should replace

```
<td width="10%"><? echo $rows['one']; ?></td>
<td width="30%"><? echo $rows['two']; ?></td>
<td width="30%"><? echo $rows['three']; ?></td>
<td width="30%"><? echo $rows['four']; ?></td>
```

with

```
<td width="10%"><?php echo $rows['one']; ?></td>
<td width="30%"><?php echo $rows['two']; ?></td>
<td width="30%"><?php echo $rows['three']; ?></td>
<td width="30%"><?php echo $rows['four']; ?></td>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! That was great help.